# Override Dockerfile ARG from docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I can't override the Dockerfile arg from docker-compose.yml when I set a default value at Dockerfile arg.

If the user just run de Dockerfile whiteout any parameter I want that docker don't break and at docker-compose.yml I want to set a better architecture.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6 as flask_api
LABEL maintainer 'https://about.me/leandro.garcias'

ARG DEBUG=False
# BD Config
ARG DATABASE_URL='sqlite:///data/app.db'
# Max register per page, when you try to get all
ARG MAX_PER_PAGE=25
# Collect log errors. https://sentry.io
ARG COLLECT_LOG_ERRORS=False
ARG SENTRY_DSN=''

RUN adduser api
USER api

WORKDIR /home/api

COPY requirements.txt manage.py contrib/boot.sh ./
COPY tests tests
COPY app app

RUN mkdir data

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBUG $DEBUG
ENV DATABASE_URL $DATABASE_URL
ENV MAX_PER_PAGE $MAX_PER_PAGE
ENV COLLECT_LOG_ERRORS $COLLECT_LOG_ERRORS
ENV SENTRY_DSN $SENTRY_DSN


RUN python -m venv venv
RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD bash boot.sh

EXPOSE 5000:5000
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  local_data:
  data:
networks:
  web:
  app:
  db:
services:
  frontend:
    image: nginx:1.13
    volumes:
      - ./contrib/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - web
      - app
    depends_on:
      - app
  app:
    image: flask_api
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - local_data:/home/api/data
    networks:
      - app
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - DEBUG = False
        # BD Config
        - DATABASE_URL = postgres://postgres:@db:5432/people
        # Max register per page, when you try to get all
        - MAX_PER_PAGE = 25
        # Collect log errors. https://sentry.io
        - COLLECT_LOG_ERRORS = False
        - SENTRY_DSN = ''
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=people
```

I need help ...

Comment: What errors are you seeing. Include the command you run to build your image and it's output, along with what you run to see your args did not apply.

Comment: I think you need to use colons (:) instead of equal signs (=).

Comment: ERROR: environment variable name 'DEBUG ' may not contain whitespace.

You might be getting this error when you build, as there shouldn't be spaces around the variable name. (docker-compose: version 3.8)

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution! Just need to set environment values. :-)

```
  app:
    image: flask_api
    environment:
      - DEBUG=False
      # BD Config
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:@db:5432/people
      # Max register per page, when you try to get all
      - MAX_PER_PAGE=25
      # Collect log errors. https://sentry.io
      - COLLECT_LOG_ERRORS=False
      - SENTRY_DSN=''
```

Comment: Adding reference to the official docs - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#using-arg-variables

"Environment variables defined using the ENV instruction always override an ARG instruction of the same name"

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2022**

ERROR: environment variable name 'DEBUG ' may not contain whitespace.

This might be the error you're getting. There shouldn't be spaces around the env. variable.

**If we are passing args to the build from docker-compose, it would override the default arg value specified in Dockerfile.**